# codeigniter libraries dependancies

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to pass objects between classes in code igniter and am currently failing. What am I doing wrong. Let me strt showing the pure.php version

Errors.php

```
<?php
class Errors
{
    public function __construct(){}
    public function setError($msg){}
}
```

OtherClass.php

```
<?php
class OtherClass
{
    public function __construct(Errors $errorObject) {}
    public function someMethod() {}
}
```

Then in my main controller..
Controller.php

```
<?php
class Main
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->errors = new Errors;
        $this->other  = new OtherClass($this->errors);
    }
}
```

By doing this. I can add errors as I go to my error Object, across any objects i instantiate from the Main controller.

Now my code igniter version looks like this

/library/Errors.php

```
<?php
class Errors
{
    public function __construct(){}
    public function setError($msg){}
}
```

/library/OtherClass.php

```
<?php
class OtherClass
{
    public function __construct(Errors $errorObject) {}
    public function someMethod() {}
}
```

Then in my main controller..
Controller.php

```
<?php

    class Main extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->load->library('Errors'); 
            $this->load->library('OtherClass',$this->errors);
        }
    }
```

When I do this I get an error in my OtherClass saying that $errorObject is not an instance of Errors. Why is the object not being passed?

Comment: If you looked at my (previous) answer and found it wanting check out the revised version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `$this->load->library` which is defined like this.

```
public function library($library, $params = NULL, $object_name = NULL)
```

`$params` is expected to be an array. If it is not then the `$params` is set to NULL.

To get around this requires a bunch of monkey biz.

`class Errors` is unchanged but `class OtherClass` needs to be changed to...

```
class OtherClass
{
    public function __construct($errorObject)
    {
        var_dump($errorObject[0]);  //so we can prove it got passed
    }

    public function someMethod(){}
}
```

Note the removal of the type hint `Error` from the constructor declaration. Also, we access index 0 of the argument. The reason lies in what happens at the controller.

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('Errors');
    $this->load->library('OtherClass', [$this->errors]);
}
```

We have to put `$this->error` in an array so that `load->library()` won't mess with it.

The alternative is to not use "The CodeIgniter Way" and use good old fashion `new' instead. The controller then is...

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('Errors');
    $this->other  = new OtherClass($this->errors);
}
```

And other class reverts to...

```
class OtherClass
{
    public function __construct(Errors $errorObject)
    {
        var_dump($errorObject);
    }

    public function someMethod(){}
}
```

Now the problem is that without adding an autoloader to the system you wind up with

> Fatal error: Class 'OtherClass' not found in ...

This [LINK](http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-tutorials/no-more-my_controller-how-you-can-create-more-than-one-base-controller/) goes to a page that talks about the various ways to add an autoloader to CI. I know this has been answered on SO too. But I'm failing to find it at the moment.